# Meteor Up Invoking deployment process: Failed

Tags: node.js, meteor, meteor-up

I tried to deploy my Meteor App on a Digital Ocean Droplet via MUP. Unfortunately it gives me the following error whil Invoking deployment process.

```
-----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
e_root_dir=/root/.node-gyp/0.10.36',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/opt/ecards/tmp/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
gyp info spawn make
gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
gyp info ok 
npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No README data
stop: Unknown instance: 
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
```

0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused
    App did not pick up! Please check app logs.
    -----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------
    t_lib.node
      SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib.node: Finished
      COPY Release/bcrypt_lib.node
    make: Leaving directory `/opt/ecards/tmp/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/build'

```
> fibers@1.0.5 install /opt/ecards/tmp/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers
> node ./build.js

`linux-x64-v8-3.14` exists; testing
Binary is fine; exiting
underscore@1.5.2 node_modules/underscore

eachline@2.3.3 node_modules/eachline
└── type-of@2.0.1

semver@4.1.0 node_modules/semver

chalk@0.5.1 node_modules/chalk
├── ansi-styles@1.1.0
├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.3
├── supports-color@0.2.0
├── strip-ansi@0.3.0 (ansi-regex@0.2.1)
└── has-ansi@0.1.0 (ansi-regex@0.2.1)

fibers@1.0.5 node_modules/fibers

source-map-support@0.2.8 node_modules/source-map-support
└── source-map@0.1.32 (amdefine@0.1.0)
Waiting for MongoDB to initialize. (5 minutes)
connected
ecards start/running, process 12126
Waiting for 30 seconds while app is booting up
Checking is app booted or not?
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

OS: Ubuntu 14.04

My mup.json settings were the following:

connection options ... -> via ssh

- setupMongo: true
- setupNode: true
- nodeVersion: 0.10.36
- setupPhantom: true

...
deployCheckWaitTime: 30

My next step was to preinstall node on my Droplet via apt-get. 0.10.25 was installed by default so i changed it via

- npm install -g n
- n 0.10.36

after that I recreated a droplet, started mup again but it showed me the same error. And Yes i first executed mup setup and then deploy ;-) 
I dont even get the error. Are there any tipps?

Thanks 
Matze

Comment: have you tried it on a ubuntu droplet?

Comment: yes i used ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Ok i got a solution. ... my URL in the mup.json File was a IP Address. The script instead expects a absolute URL like http://example.com. After i changed it and rerun setup + deploy it worked out. Anyway thanks for your help :-)

Comment: I think you should post above comment as an answer :)